# Updating external maven dependancies without full redeploy

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven

Let me preface this by saying that I only have a basic understanding of Maven. I need to get a better grasp of it and that's where my question comes in.

*EDIT*
I have a large tomcat webapp, that has multiple external dependencies(JARs) and I only need to update one of them and move it into production.

For lack of better wording/terms, how do I update my external dependencies and deploy only those without re-deploying my entire project? This external dependency is located in a remote repo, I have since updated the version number in my pom file and I need to update only this dependency and then deploy only it to my production systems.

Also if anyone has any beginner maven tutorials/primers they could suggest that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have a WAR project, for example, and you need to update some library in the WAR to a new version and deploy it, then in the Maven world, you've created a new version of your project, and you would treat it as any other change: release it, test it, and push the new version into production. In practice, of course, you could just put the new JAR out on your app server and remove the old one. That's a manual fix, though, and depending on how your process normally runs, it could be dangerous and fragile. Doing a normal release is the "right" way.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. It is a tomcat webapp. So I have multiple JAR files copied to the tomcat server hosting the app. 

I tried just moving the single JAR file itself, but it seems to have its own dependencies because it just errors out.

Comment: Right. Maven's role in a project is to create a correct artifact. In this case, that's a WAR file. I'd still just let Maven do what it does and deploy a new WAR. Messing around with dependencies manually usually isn't very productive.